# C fill up buffer and write out when reached size

Tags: c, buffer

I've got a 4Kb cache buffer. I want to fill it up with some data in increments of 512 bytes until it's full and then do something with it, say pass it to another function, and clear it for the next lot of data. That's all fine, but I can't get it to write out every 4Kb. Here's what I have:

```
uint32_t chunk = 512;
uint32_t cache_size = 4096;
uint32_t chunks_per_cache = 8;
uint8_t cache[4096];

void buff_write(uint8_t *buff, uint8_t count) {

    uint8_t index = 0;
    uint8_t wrote = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < count; ++index) {

        if (index % chunks_per_cache == 0 && index != 0) {
            // operate on cached buffer and clear it
            wrote = 0;
            memset(cache, 0, sizeof(cache));
        }
        printf("buff %d Kb\n", index * chunk);

        // advance buffer
        memcpy(cache + wrote * chunk, buff, chunk);
        buff += chunk;
        wrote++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // init some data
    uint8_t data[cache_size];
    memset(data, '?', 1024);
    memset(data+1024, '-', 1024);
    memset(data+2048, '!', 1024);
    memset(data+3072, '#', 1024);

    // write from data to cache
    buff_write(data, sizeof(data)/chunk);

    printf("leftover cache:\n");
    printf("%s\n", cache);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, I want the leftover data to be completely empty. By the time buff_write finished, which is cleared in the statement:

```
if (index % chunks_per_cache == 0 && index != 0)
```

The question is how to keep the iteration and offset values and make the if statement execute inside the for loop if there's 8 chunks, less will be cached as usual. If I increase the size of data, it will iterate over more than 8 chunks no problem. I think I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: That is `if` not `for` . Edit it .

Comment: This is wrong: `printf("wrote: %s\n", cache);`  `cache` is not a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Ohh  i see it .

Comment: Typo fixed. Doesn't matter how I print the sting, that's not the problem. Printif is just there to say that the buffer is written or passed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This code resets `cache` every 8 bytes:

```
uint32_t chunks_per_cache = 8;
    .
    .
    .
        if (index % chunks_per_cache == 0 && index != 0) {
            // operate on cached buffer
            printf("wrote: %s\n", cache);
            wrote = 0;
            memset(cache, 0, sizeof(cache));
        }
```

That code is not going to do what you want - fill up your `cache`.

Comment: That's fine, I want it to reset the cache every 8 chunks (512 bytes), not bytes.